# How to solve "Unable to find git in your PATH" on Flutter?

Tags: git, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I've just tried to install Flutter on Linux and when I try to run a flutter command (flutter doctor), I'm getting

```
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: please create an answer for that and accept don't just write solved and thanks

Comment: Thanks, someone already did it. Will do so next time.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov accept the answer if its correct

Comment: I deleted the .gradle file and it worked well. Actually, it reduces the indexing time also.

Comment: For Windows, I've realised it's something to do with Admin account vs. regular. Running `flutter doctor -v` in Admin mode works, in regular mode does not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Install it using following command.

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 81):

Here is my solution for Windows 11 64bit, flutter 3.7.3, installed via chocolatey. It has simply to do with enforced git security settings which can detect dubious ownship for the flutter repository. Just add the flutter base directory to the git directory exception list:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/tools/flutter-base-dir
```

or change the ownership of the flutter base directory with [fix unsafe git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901632/fatal-error-unsafe-repository-home-repon-is-owned-by-someone-else/71949648#71949648)

Comment: This fixes my problem. Been reinstalling git 5 times not including yesterday attempts. Geez!

Comment: Didnt work. I already installed git.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Windows sadly. The only think I have worked out is that it work if you are in terminal/powershell in Admin mode, but not as a regular user.

Comment: Thank you! Please know your solution saved my sanity 3 years after you posted it.

Comment: flutter really should clarify their error message for this one. I would never have guessed this was the issue looking at the error message

Comment: For people trying this on Windows make sure you use forward slashes in the path, backslashes do not work. And if you're using FVM don't use the symbolic link, use the actual physical path. Took me an hour to figure that out.

Comment: there is no flutter base directory in my case
only tools/dart-sdk

Comment: worked for me. Pay attention to slashes, don't do \ but /. I installed via chocolatey and did git config --global --add safe.directory C:/tools/flutter

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I'm using Windows 11.

Answer (score 48):

If solutions listed do not work for you, try this one

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

This is the only solution which works for me [github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123995](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123995)

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use '*' here - you're bypassing a security measure which is there for a reason. You should only need to add the directory where Flutter is located. If that doesn't work note that on Windows you MUST use forward slashes in the path, not backslashes. Also, if you're using FVM, use the real path, not the FVM symbolic link. (eg `git config --global --add safe.directory 'C:/Users/james/fvm/versions/3.10.6'`)

Answer (score 41):

Add

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32
```

to your PATH variable

Do not create new variable for git but add them as I did one after another separating them by ;

Comment: This solution can work only for Windows, it must be said (the question is about Linux)

Comment: What does teh semicolon do?

Comment: In user variable section or system variable section?

Comment: I have been trying for days to get it solved, tried so many things. And today after two days when I tried to fix my issue, this solution just made it running fine.

Comment: You need a way to separate the entries. Each operating system can use whatever character, but the two most popular are semi-colon (on Windows) and colon (on most systems Unix, e.g. Mac OS X). @rfii

Comment: system variable section @SumitShukla

Comment: Glad to hear that @Rizwan Sohaib

Comment: Doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. I've tried everything but **running cmd as Administrator** solved my problem.

Comment: This solution can work only for Windows, it must be said (the question is about Linux)

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that. But i just shared to help windows users which are directed here like me.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to work out why this is - not sure I want to be in admin mode all the time.

Answer (score 11):

just add `C:\Windows\System32` to your system variable PATH.
it works

Comment: This solution can work only for Windows, it must be said (the question is about Linux)

Comment: For windows this was the answer that fixed my issue

Answer (score 5):

I also got the same problem because my system didn't had git installed. So I downloaded git from https://git-scm.com/downloads and installed it and just after installing, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If nothing above helps, this might be a possible solution. Note, this is for Windows.

To me nothing seemed to work so I ended up digging up flutter batch files. The error is located at **%FLUTTER_ROOT%\bin\internal\shared.bat**. This is how this line of code looks like:

```
  REM Check that git exists and get the revision
  SET git_exists=false
  2>NUL (
    PUSHD "%flutter_root%"
    FOR /f %%r IN ('git rev-parse HEAD') DO (
      SET git_exists=true
      SET revision=%%r
    )
    POPD
  )
  REM If git didn't execute we don't have git. Exit without /B to avoid retrying.
  if %git_exists% == false echo Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. && EXIT 1
```

This line **"2>NUL ("** tells windows batch file to not display any internal errors. You can comment it out like this: (Don't forget the closing bracket)

```
  REM 2>NUL (
    PUSHD "%flutter_root%"
    FOR /f %%r IN ('git rev-parse HEAD') DO (
      SET git_exists=true
      SET revision=%%r
    )
    POPD
  REM )
```

After saving that and running flutter command again I got this error: "Fatal: Not A Git Repository". This didn't make any sense since it had .git directory and running "git rev-parse HEAD" in root worked fine.

Reason why this is happening might be because terminal isn't really pointing to current folder and instead it points to something completely else. To me it was "C:\Windows". I figured this part by setting git_exists=true, after that flutter installed without problems. When I tried to run my flutter project, I got error that there is no pubspec.yaml file in my root even though there was. So, tried to test it by creating  another flutter project and then I got error that flutter can't create project in "C:\Windows".

So, to fix this, I had to do following:

- Go to Registry Editor. You can find it in Windows search or by pressing "Windows key" + R. Type in "regedit" and it will open.
- After that, got to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor", find AutoRun key and delete it.
- If there is no AutoRun key, it might be located in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" instead of
  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE".

Really strange error but this was causing flutter to sometimes look in folder specified at this key instead of current folder.

Answer (score 3):

**Uninstall** and **reinstall** GIT solved my problem.

Comment: i reinstalled git bash and it worked for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:
This solution is for Windows only.**

Add these variables to Path in environment variable:

(How to add to Path Read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72341522/8890476)

1. C:\src\flutter\bin
2. C:\Windows\System32
3. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
4. C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
5. C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

Alternative:
Try use windows PowerShell (admin), it work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The correct windows answer is more to do with needing to be in admin mode not about setting the environment path. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 2):

You can download 64-bit Git for Windows Setup
https://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 2):

FOR WINDOWS : If you chose visual studio code during git installation and have multiple user accounts on windows then all you need to do is uninstall git and reinstall git choosing vim as default editor not visual studio code. You also get a warning when choosing visual studio code during git installation. Pay attention to that.
For me setting visual studio code as default and having multiple User account was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Install Git
and run the below command
**git config --global --add safe.directory C:/tools/flutter-base-dir**

Comment: If this does not work, you can try this one git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
Actually this is the only solution which works for me https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123995

Answer (score 1):

I was having everything set correctly but I was still facing the error I only had to reopen Android Studio as Administration.. I hope this works for anyone

Answer (score 1):

I have tried more steps not worked , but at last success. You need go **''environment variables''** , then in the **''System variables''** create a new variable name **'git'** and set variable value **'C:\Program Files\Git\bin'**. Then ok. Close your vscode or all cmd file. Then again open and try **flutter doctor** you should success surely.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in windows 10
C:\src\flutter\bin
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try installing git from here according to your linux distro
https://git-scm.com/download/linux

Answer (score 0):

if it still not worked even after applying the above environment variables then Just run Android Studio as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other fix that modified flutter.bat but those did not work for me.  Find your shared.bat and manually set the git_exists to true.

C:\tools\flutter\bin\internal\shared.bat

```
SET git_exists=true
2>NUL (
  PUSHD "%flutter_root%"
  FOR /f %%r IN ('git rev-parse HEAD') DO (
    SET git_exists=true
    SET revision=%%r
  )
  POPD
)
```

You can set the variable to true or add a SET git_exists=true after the block.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run e.g. `git fetch` in flutter directory and check if there is no errors for fetching flutter repository.

In my case it was an error in git global config.
After fixing it everything works fine and i am able to run `flutter doctor`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything and none worked, I reopen Android Studio as Administration and it worked...

I hope this works for anyone

Answer (score 0):

I Windows you can try re-installing Git using default settings. It should not affect your other apps that use git.

This is my Visual Studio code Terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you use Windows , you must run cmd ( or any terminal ) with "Run As Administrator" and then exec this command :

```
git config --global --add safe.directory *
```

Answer (score -1):

```
C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Windows\System32
```

just add this path

Comment: It isn't an answer! What do you mean "just believe me". Detail your answer, please

Comment: Please expand your answer, this is not a satisfactory answer!

Answer (score -2):

It worked successfully when I started Android Studio as Administrator

Comment: 3 other answers -- on this page -- already mention running as Administrator.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Have I braked any rule or something which is against community guidelines?

Comment: Yes; in the Help Center, under the section for Answering, is a page titled [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). In that page, it says: "Answer posts that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are ... exact duplicates of other answers". Having duplicate answers means that voting is spread out among those duplicates, making it harder for future visitors to find the best answer.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you. I'll keep in mind next time.