# How to fix "unable to find Git in your path " error , despite providing required path

Tags: git, flutter, path, environment-variables, git-bash

Whenever i try to run a flutter command (in cmd), the following error occurs :

> 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

I found the similar error here
[How to solve "Unable to find git in your PATH" on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51263438/12919436) and tried everything

things I've done:

- included all essential git paths i.e.

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32

- (did the above step many times , restarted computer and tried again = fail
  )
- checked flutter bin path
- tried running cmd as administrator
- tried running command in flutter console

None of the above worked as the error still prevails.

EDIT : I uninstalled Git completely , then reinstalled it (choosing the right options) , checked environment variables and everything , gave the flutter command in cmd , and it still shows the same error! I don't know what to do now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path should not include git.exe, only its parent folder.

See my example if simplified PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

By adding:

```
set PATH=C:\Flutter\flutter\bin;%PATH%
```

The OP confirms [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49530056#49530056) that it is working.

Comment: ( The git.exe was removed after i reinstalled git )

Comment: I entered the mentioned commands and now I have a different error:'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Savvy Sure: add the path of flutter as well. `set PATH=C:\path\to\Flutter;%PATH%`

Comment: I already added the following path   C:\Users\Flutter\flutter\bin ...gave the above command but still same error..I've also added a screenshot of cmd error in the post

Comment: @Savvy Try the same set of commands in a new CMD (in which "where" is recognized)

Comment: No no , it didn't work ( my system got incredibly slow so I reinstalled windows overnight , now after setting everything , I have installed flutter and git again and same error, I tried PowerShell too , it's the same "where" error)

Comment: @Savvy In your screenshot, you used `set GH=C:\path\to\git`: you did replace `C:\path\to\git` by your actual Git installation folder, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215146/discussion-between-savvy-and-vonc).

Comment: Worked for me. I needed to set it in the console like above rather than manually through the environment variable interface in windows

Answer (score 1):

For me this error came for different reason, recording it here so that if someone searches they can benefit.

Firstly I found this error is thrown from this code

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/bin/internal/shared.bat#L68

This shared.bat is called by flutter.bat, which is triggered by the flutter daemon. If you see a few lines above, the script tries to just run

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

in the flutter root directory and fails.

When I ran this manually in that folder it threw following error

> C:\Users<<>>\fvm\versions\3.7.5>git rev-parse HEAD
> fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'C:/Users/<<>>/fvm/versions/3.7.5'

Then I just ran the below command suggested along the error by git and it resovled the above error. After this flutter daemon started without any issue

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Users/<<>>/fvm/versions/3.7.5
```