# How can I solve the flutter daemon failed to start in vscode?

Tags: flutter, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I launched git and make the flutter project in vscode. But I can't make any project and see this error `The flutter daemon failed to start`. How can I solve this problem? I already try `flutter doctor`, but it didn't help. This is my log. Please help me.

```
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\app\Samsung\product\21c\dbhomeXE\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\system32
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Bandizip\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\Samsung\.dotnet\tools
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Took 135ms to search for projects (5 levels)
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Took 1ms to filter out excluded projects (0 exclusion rules)
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Found Flutter project at C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4:
            Mobile? false
            Web? false
            Create Trigger? true
            Flutter Repo? false
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter.bat
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter.bat in:
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4 -> C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4\.flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4\.flutter -> C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4\.flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4\vendor\flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4\vendor\flutter -> C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4\vendor\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\flutter-sdk
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\flutter-sdk -> C:\Users\Samsung\flutter-sdk\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         /google/flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         /google/flutter -> \google\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\app\Samsung\product\21c\dbhomeXE\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath -> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32 -> C:\Windows\system32\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows -> C:\Windows\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem -> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ -> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ -> C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\ -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\ -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\ -> C:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\ -> C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Bandizip\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Bandizip\ -> C:\Program Files\Bandizip\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd -> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps -> C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\.dotnet\tools
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\.dotnet\tools -> C:\Users\Samsung\.dotnet\tools\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 -> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin -> C:\flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin -> C:\flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\flutter\bin -> C:\flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\flutter for flutter.bat
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk -> C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\app\Samsung\product\21c\dbhomeXE\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath -> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32 -> C:\Windows\system32\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows -> C:\Windows\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem -> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ -> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ -> C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\ -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\ -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\ -> C:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\ -> C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Bandizip\
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Bandizip\ -> C:\Program Files\Bandizip\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd -> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps -> C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\.dotnet\tools
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\.dotnet\tools -> C:\Users\Samsung\.dotnet\tools\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 -> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk -> C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk -> C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk -> C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk for dart.exe
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Experiment random number is 13 for experiment 'sdkDaps'. Experiment is enabled for <= 100
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Experiment 'sdkDaps' is activating (not first time)
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Experiment random number is 13 for experiment 'sdkDaps'. Experiment is enabled for <= 50
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Experiment 'sdkDaps' is activating (not first time)
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Experiment random number is 13 for experiment 'sdkDaps'. Experiment is enabled for <= 10
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Experiment 'sdkDaps' does not apply and will not be activated
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] !! ⚠️ PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING ⚠️ !!
Dart Code extension: 3.74.0
Flutter extension: 3.74.0 (not activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
App Host: desktop
Version: win 1.83.1

Workspace type: Flutter (LSP)

Dart (3.1.2): C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
Flutter (3.13.5): C:\flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat with args ["daemon"]
[12:17:36 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  in C:\flutter
[12:17:36 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code","FLUTTER_ROOT":"C:\\flutter"}}
[12:17:36 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info]     PID: 10040
[12:17:36 PM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 13396) Spawned C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat create --template app --overwrite . in C:\Users\Samsung\VsCodeSource\capstone_vs\cap_prac4
[12:17:36 PM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 13396) Logging data for process...
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Loaded 20000 package names from vscode-userdata:/c%3A/Users/Samsung/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/dart-code.dart-code/package_cache.json
[12:17:36 PM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 13396) exited (1, null)
[12:17:36 PM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 13396) Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
[12:17:36 PM] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 13396) closed (1, null)
[12:17:36 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["language-server","--protocol=lsp","--client-id=VS-Code","--client-version=3.74.0"]
[12:17:36 PM] [Analyzer] [Info]     PID: 17380
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Returning cached results for project search
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
[12:17:36 PM] [DevTools] [Info] Spawning C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["devtools","--machine","--try-ports","10","--allow-embedding"]
[12:17:36 PM] [DevTools] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code","FLUTTER_ROOT":"C:\\flutter"}}
[12:17:36 PM] [DevTools] [Info]     PID: 10040
[12:17:36 PM] [General] [Info] Found 0 folders requiring "pub get" or "pub upgrade":
[12:17:36 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 6485
[12:17:36 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":10040,"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code","version":"1.83.1"},"locale":"en","rootPath":"c:\\Users\\Samsung\\VsCodeSource\\capstone_vs\\cap_prac4","rootUri":"file:///C%3A/Users/Samsung/VsCodeSource/capstone_vs/cap_prac4","capabilities":{"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"workspaceEdit":{"documentChanges":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"],"failureHandling":"textOnlyTransactional","normalizesLineEndings":…
[12:17:36 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] <== Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

Not only vscode also android studio show me that error. If I delete git, there is no problem. But I really want to use git in my laptop.
I want to use flutter and git normally

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51263438/8144311) can help you.